# Function to set the state of a nested object with argument variable as key

Tags: reactjs, typescript, setstate

I want to update an object state with a function `updateDatas`. I pass `key`, potentially `subKey`, and `value` as argument of this function.

```
interface Datas {
  code: number;
  item1: Item;
}

interface Item {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const [datas, setDatas] = useState({
  code: 42,
  item1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo'
  }
});

function updateDatas(key: string, subKey: string, value: any) {
  if (subKey) {
    setDatas({...datas, key: {...datas.key, subKey: value}});
  } else {
    setDatas({...datas, key: value});
  }
}

updateDatas('code', 23);
updateDatas('item1', 'name', 'bar');
```

But it doesn't work, I have this Typescript error :

> Argument of type '{ key: any; code: number; item1: Item; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'key' does not exist in type 'SetStateAction'.ts(2345)

Comment: I think you have to wrap key and subKey in square brackets
```setDatas({...datas, [key]: {...datas.key, [subKey]: value}});```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to update the key `subKey` instead of using the key the variable `subKey` has as string. Same with `key`. Do the following:

```
function updateDatas(key: string, subKey: string, value: any) {
  if (subKey) {
    setDatas({...datas, [key]: {...datas[key] as Item, [subKey]: value}});
  } else {
    setDatas({...datas, [key]: value});
  }
}
```

Anyway you should have some incongruence between interfaces because `key` is of type `string` instead of `keysof Datas` and the same with `subKey` (`keysof Item`).

```
function updateDatas(key: keysof Datas, subKey: keysof Item, value: any) {
  if (subKey) {
    setDatas({...datas, [key]: {...datas[key], [subKey]: value}});
  } else {
    setDatas({...datas, [key]: value});
  }
}
```

EDIT: The same with the value, since in your interfaces you want the value to be other thing instead of `any`. You should look for a workaround around this.

Comment: `...datas.key` give ts error : `Property 'key' does not exist on type 'Datas'.`. `...datas[key]` doesn't work too.

Comment: `Spread types may only be created from object types. ts(2698)`

Comment: Oh yes because you should type better the params of your function since it can be any `string` key, hence TS doesn't know if that `datas[key]` is an object to spread, since i.e. `datas.code` is `42`. Check my response please

Comment: I have made changes (`keysof` doesn't work for me, but `keyof` yes) : 
`function updateDatas(key: keyof Datas, subKey: keyof Item, value: string | number)`
But `datas[key]` still doesn't work

Comment: The value could be of type `string | number | Item` but still isn't well typed. I would try another approach instead of having this all wrapped in one function. I don't know your use case but it might be other way. Please consider creating another question and mark the answer as correct if it is suitable

Comment: `...datas[key] as Item` works. You can update your answer. Thanks.